# Is this really not a legal way to initialize a list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to initialize a string list to use in a later method. I don't know what size the list needs to be because the data sets that will be passed to the program are not consistently sized. Because of this, I'm dynamically adding items to the list. However, when I initialize the list in the space above what would be considered `main()` like this,

```
List<string> studentData;
```

and call it in a public method like this,

```
studentData.AddRange(student); // Student is an array
```

I get an exception that says,

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of 
>   an object' studentData was null.

but earlier in my code I called initialized a different list like this and it worked just fine,

```
List<string> fileInput; // Holds comma delimited file text
.
. 
.
fileInput = text.Split(',').ToList();`
```

So then I went to [DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list) to figure out how to initialize a non empty list. Per the code examples this should have worked,

```
List<string> studentData = new List<string>();
studentData.Add("Thing");
```

but `studentData` got green underlined with warning text

> studentData is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 
>   null.

and `studentData.Add("Thing");` got red underlined with error text

> The name 'studentData.Add' doesn't exist in the current context. 
>   The name 'studentData' doesn't exist in the current context.

and `("Thing")` was handled separately as well.

> Type expected.
>   Tuple must contain at least two elements.
>   ) expected.
>   Invalid token '"Thing"' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

[image]

I'm still fairly new to C# and none these errors makes sense to me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In the first example you try to call method from uninitialized object and in the second you assign value to uninitialized object, that's the diiference.

Comment: Have you tried making `studentData.AddRange(student);` into `studentData.AddRange(student.ToString());` ?

Comment: @ShanCoralde `studentData.AddRange(student.ToString());` will raise a conversion error if typed like that. I did try to use a string instead of an array, but `studentData` still says it's not assigned and I still get the original error.

Comment: Have you tried @diberium's answer below?

Comment: I am sorry but you did not post the exact code to reproduce the last error message. Otherwise I would try to explain this also :)

Comment: I biffed it and grabbed the wrong screen shot. The one up now is the one I meant to grab.

Comment: I could reproduce the token and context not found messages, which I explained in my edit. but the green line is not reproducible for me. Sometimes you get confounds from older built-version where the message was correct, but now you changed your code, the situation is different but the compiler still tells you that the situation persists. I really don't know

Comment: Well not really, I input the same code that's mentioned in the block quotes above the image and the image shows that. The error shows up after it tries to run. In any case though the explanation you provided and the answer from @diberium gets me further than where I was before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> studentData;
```

Just declare a variable `studentData`, its type is `List<string>`, and the value is `null`.

```
List<string> studentData = new List<string>();
```

This will create an empty list and assign to `studentData`.

Comment: That got rid of the `NullReference`. Didn't even think to try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same, I didn't faced any issue. Please rebuild the solution and check once again.

```
List<string> studentData = new List<string>();
studentData.Add("Thing");
```

Answer (score 1):

1)

> when I initialize the list in the space above what would be considered main() like this,

```
List<string> studentData;
```

In this case you simply **declare** the variable but you have not initialized it yet. There is no value assigned to it. Hence the default value is `null` and you get this nice exception.

2)

List studentData = new List();
    studentData.Add("Thing");

> but studentData got green underlined with warning text

This error arrises when you declare `studentData` once on class level outside the scope of the method and once inside the method **locally**, and you choose the same name!
 So the compiler will favor the local variable and use this reference. The variable with the same name on class level (which is really a different variable although it has the same name) will not be used, hence your green line message

[image: code picture]

3)

> The name 'studentData.Add' doesn't exist in the current context. The name 'studentData' doesn't exist in the current context.

This error arises when the compiler cannot find `studentData` at all! so that means that you have not even declared the variable either locally or on class level. (One tip here: if you declare it outside of main in a console application you need to make the variable `static` or create an instance of `Program`, otherwise you canno use the variable, since `Main` is `static`.)

**EDIT:**

Your posted screenshot paints a little different picture. This error message is misleading unfortunately. Actually the compiler wants to tell you that you cannot execute a method call like `Add(..)` outside of a method body! This is why you get the [Compiler Error CS1519](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1519)

The compiler now tries to infer what you might mean with this statement:

- it thinks that you are trying to access a variable with the name `studentData.Add` which is not declared.
- it thinks that you are trying to access a variable with the name `studentData` which is not declared.
- it thinks that you are trying to access a variable with the name `Add` which is not declared.

Comment: the image you have attached isn't the way I tried to setup the initialization. I had `List<string> studentData = new List<string>(); studentData.Add("Thing");` in the class level and was getting that, but your explanation does makes sense.

Comment: @rocky please post a screen shot of the way that you did showing the green line with the "studentData is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null." message

Comment: I went back and tried putting that error in the same way after fixing it, but  it's not giving the green line anymore...

Comment: @rocky now that is an entirely different picture! hold on a sec

Comment: I grabbed the wrong one I just fixed it. Sorry about that.